# How can I remove the space between the GroupHeaderTemplate and the ItemTemplate in a CollectionView on Windows .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, maui, collectionview

Having not had an answer to my question, I am relaunching the subject for which I would like to have the solution. I am developing a contact list in .NET MAUI. However I have padding that goes around my GroupHeaderTemplate. This issue only occurs on Windows. As you can see I don't have this problem on Android.

Here is the result on Android and Windows.

Android :
[image: List on Android]

Windows :
[image: List on Windows]

```xml
                <CollectionView Grid.Row="2"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
                                SelectionMode="None"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"    
                                IsGrouped="True">
                    
                    <!-- En-tête de groupe -->
                    <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                   FontSize="12" HeightRequest="20"
                                   FontFamily="{x:Static constants:FontFamilies.TEXT_BOLD}"
                                   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource HeaderGrey}"
                                   Padding="20,0,0,4" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Contact">
                            <VerticalStackLayout>
   
                                <Label HeightRequest="39"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       Padding="20,0,0,0">

                                    <Label.FormattedText>
                                        <FormattedString>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding Firstname}"/>
                                            <Span Text=" "/>
                                            <Span Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                  FontFamily="{x:Static constants:FontFamilies.TEXT_BOLD}"/>
                                        </FormattedString>
                                    </Label.FormattedText>

                                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ContactSelected" 
                                                              Command="{Binding Source=
                                                                                    {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ContactViewModel}}, 
                                                                                                    Path=DisplayContactCommand}"
                                                              CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>

                                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource SeparatorCellGrey}"/>

                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

I have tried everything. Maybe there is a handler to modify for Windows platform but I can't find it. Hoping to have a solution for this problem that I have had for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is just the case as you said.

I did a test on my side. The result is that on windows, there is a minimum height by default, even if we set the Label height very small, `CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate` still occupies the default minimum height. We can increase the height of the `GroupHeader`, but after trying to reduce the height of the `GroupHeader`, we find that its height cannot be smaller after reaching the minimum height.

And as you said, on Android, everything works fine.

For this problem on windows, you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Thanks very much for your support for maui and feedback.

Best regards!

Jessie